# Angular7 Cannot Send Thr Correct Http Request(There is no record in Chrome Network sniffer when 'http.get')

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient, angular7

I want to send a HTTP GET request within @Angular/common/HttpClint, but there is no response, even chrome network sniffer cannot detect any network activities.

When I tried to `console.log`, this was the result:

```
 console.log(this.http.get("http://localhost/users"));
```

Then I found that the result of console was:

`Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

And chrome network sniffer didn't detect any XHR related to my action.

Why?

Can it be because of using @ng-cli to create this project?

I init this Angular project via @ng-cli.

when I use an example project [(Heroes Example)](https://www.angular.cn/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip), there are no problems.

But each of my project that created by @ng-cil(*ng new project*) has that problem.

**More Info:**

Result of the console:

Comment: Please don't make everything so big and bold, edit it to use appropriate markup. People are less likely to want to help you if you just shout at them.

Comment: Improved formatting and spelling and grammar. However the "result of the console" section has no information.

Comment: Okay~
I got that~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `http.get` to get any response.

```
 console.log(this.http.get("http://localhost/users").subscribe());
```

From angular docs:

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call
>   subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true
>   for all HttpClient methods.

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks a lot~!  it confused me a long time